# Reference Error :Not reading the .ejs file present in views folder

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to redirect to a feedback page after login but it is just loading the layout.ejs file and after checking view page source it is showing a reference error..

feed.ejs file

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/company/changepassword">Change password</a></li>
            <li><a href="/company/logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
 <h2 align="center">Industry Expectations & Feedback</h2>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <div class="container col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-10 " style="margin-bottom:30px;">
    <label>Date: </label>
    <br>

    <label>Name of the Company: </label> <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <label>Name of the Authorized Person:</label><input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>


    <br>
    <br>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col-md-4" >Description</th>
      <th scope="col-md-4"></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" >1. Number Of years you have been Associated with our campus Placements:</th>
      <td>
      <label>1 Year</label><input type="radio" name="rad">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>2 Year</label><input type="radio" name="rad">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>3 Year</label><input type="radio" name="rad">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>More Than 3 Years</label><input type="radio" name="rad">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2. Average number of Students recruited by your company, through our campus:</th>
      <td>
      <label>Less than 10</label><input type="radio" name="rad1">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Less than 25</label><input type="radio" name="rad1">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Less than 50</label><input type="radio" name="rad1">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>More Than 50</label><input type="radio" name="rad1">
      &nbsp &nbsp

      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3. The course/courses from which you recruit our students regularly :</th>
      <td>
      <label>DAC</label><input type="checkbox">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>WiMC</label><input type="checkbox">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>DESD</label><input type="checkbox">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>DSSD</label><input type="checkbox">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>DAS</label><input type="checkbox">
      &nbsp &nbsp

      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col-md-10" colspan="2">4. Quality of manpower recruited through Campus during the previous years :</th>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">a) Technical Skills:</th>
      <td>
      <label>Excellent</label><input type="radio" name="rad2">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Good</label><input type="radio" name="rad2">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Average</label><input type="radio" name="rad2">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Poor</label><input type="radio" name="rad2">
      &nbsp &nbsp

      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">b) Communication Skills:</th>
      <td>
      <label>Excellent</label><input type="radio" name="rad3">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Good</label><input type="radio" name="rad3">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Average</label><input type="radio" name="rad3">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Poor</label><input type="radio" name="rad3">
      &nbsp &nbsp

      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">c) Overall Performance:</th>
      <td>
      <label>Excellent</label><input type="radio" name="rad4">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Good</label><input type="radio" name="rad4">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Average</label><input type="radio" name="rad4">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Poor</label><input type="radio" name="rad4">
      &nbsp &nbsp

      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">5. Attrition rate among the employees recruited through our campus:</th>
      <td>
      <label>Less than 1%</label><input type="radio" name="rad5">
      <label>Less than 5%</label><input type="radio" name="rad5">
      <label>Less than 10%</label><input type="radio" name="rad5">
      <label>Greater than 10%</label><input type="radio" name="rad5">

      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">6. How do you rate our campus Placement activity:</th>
      <td>
      <label>Excellent</label><input type="radio" name="rad6">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Good</label><input type="radio" name="rad6">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Average</label><input type="radio" name="rad6">
      &nbsp &nbsp
      <label>Poor</label><input type="radio" name="rad6">
      &nbsp &nbsp

      </td>



    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col-md-10" colspan="2">7.Any additional attributes expected from the students (Technical/Non-Technical):</th>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col-md-10" colspan="2"><textarea style="width:100%"></textarea></th>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col-md-10" colspan="2">8:Your comments and suggestions for improvement in C-DAC ACTS Courses:</th>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col-md-10" colspan="2"><textarea style="width:100%"></textarea></th>


    </tr>
        <tr>
      <th scope="col-md-10" colspan="2">9:Any suggestion for improvement of our campus activity:</th>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col-md-10" colspan="2"><textarea style="width:100%"></textarea></th>


    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<center><input type ="submit" class=" btn-lg btn-success"/></center>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
```

company.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('company/company', { error: req.flash('error') });
    //console.log(res.render('company/company', { error: req.flash('error') }));
});
router.get('/feedback', function (req, res) {
    res.render('company/feed', { error: req.flash('error') });
      });
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body.username;
    var pass = req.body.password;
    console.log(user);
    console.log(pass);
    res.redirect('/company/feedback');    
});
```

app.js file has all the routing and which is done perfectly as follows:

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const session = require('express-session');
const expressLayout = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
// app.use(express.json());
// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(expressLayout);
app.use(session({ secret: 'surajbalwantshinde', resave: false, saveUninitialized: true}));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cors());
app.use(flash());
// app.use(function(req, res){res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');});

const companyRouter =require('./routes/company');
app.use('/company',companyRouter);
```

error that it is flashing on view source:

```
<!-- <h1>E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\views\company\feed.ejs:203
    201| &lt;/div&gt;
    202| &lt;!-- &lt; &lt;div class=&#34;container-fluid&#34;&gt;
 &gt;&gt; 203|     &lt;% if(err.length&gt;0) {%&gt;
    204|     &lt;script&gt; $(function () { swal(&#34;&lt;%=err%&gt;&#34;, &#34;Try again!!&#34;, &#34;error&#34;) })&lt;/script&gt;
    205|     &lt;%}%&gt;
    206|     &lt;% if(msg.length&gt;0) {%&gt;

err is not defined</h1> -->
<!-- <h2></h2> -->
<!-- <pre>ReferenceError: E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\views\company\feed.ejs:203
    201| &lt;/div&gt;
    202| &lt;!-- &lt; &lt;div class=&#34;container-fluid&#34;&gt;
 &gt;&gt; 203|     &lt;% if(err.length&gt;0) {%&gt;
    204|     &lt;script&gt; $(function () { swal(&#34;&lt;%=err%&gt;&#34;, &#34;Try again!!&#34;, &#34;error&#34;) })&lt;/script&gt;
    205|     &lt;%}%&gt;
    206|     &lt;% if(msg.length&gt;0) {%&gt;

err is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:592:12), &lt;anonymous&gt;:11:8)
    at returnedFn (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:623:17)
    at tryHandleCache (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:480:10)
    at View.render (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:77:18)
    at E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\routes\company.js:102:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)</pre> -->
```

my desired output should be a proper feedback form after login page redirects to feedback on the feedback page rather than a blank page......

Answer (score 0):

Based on this portion of the error message, there is a syntax error in one of your `.ejs` files:

```
err is not defined</h1> -->
<!-- <h2></h2> -->
<!-- <pre>ReferenceError: E:\project pictures\StudentPortal\views\company\feed.ejs:203
```

Comment: please go through my ejs file as well